# Exact match using InStr in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, search

I have written a `search function` in my program, which will return whether a particular string is available in one `text file`.Now comes the issue function not doing an Exact match.

Please consider the following sample data which will be inside my `text file`,here my function fail to identify both values are different. 
`sample data 1 : fol1_fol2_SMPTR` and `sample data 2 : fol1_fol2_SMPTR1`.

Please find my search code below.

```
strFileName = "C:\data\datafile.txt"
```

Consider `sample data 1 and 2` as input to variable `strSearch`

```
Function sheetExists(strSearch, strFileName) As Boolean
    sheetExists = False
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim lngLine As Long
    Dim blnFound As Boolean
    f = FreeFile
    Open strFileName For Input As #f
    Do While Not EOF(f)
        lngLine = lngLine + 1
        Line Input #f, strLine
        If InStr(1, strLine, strSearch, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Search string found in line " & lngLine, vbInformation
            blnFound = True
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    Close #f
    If blnFound Then
        sheetExists = True
    End If
End Function
```

Let me know your valuable suggestions and thought.

Comment: Wait, you just want exact string compare after a delimiter? Try `LTrim$(Mid$(strLine, InStr(1, strLine, ":") + 1)) = strSearch`.

Comment: Should i replace the given code with the code in my if condition inside Search function?

Comment: Yes, replace your `InStr(...) > 0` with it.

Comment: Awesome, smooth as butter... Please post this as answer, little more detail on the code will help others in future. Cheers...

Comment: Done. Hope you'll find the description useful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've described, it sounds like you want to get the text on a line after a delimiter (in this case, `:`).

1. Find the position of the delimiter, `:`.

   `InStr(1, strLine, ":")`
2. Add 1 to it to get the position of the character immediately following it.

   `InStr(1, strLine, ":") + 1`
3. Use the `Mid$` function to get the string starting from that position to the end of that string (note that `Mid$` has 3 parameters; ignoring the last one will assume you want the string starting from the position given by the second parameter to the end of the string).

   `Mid$(strLine, InStr(1, strLine, ":") + 1)`
4. Trim the left side of the string using `LTrim$` to remove any leading whitespaces.

   `LTrim$(Mid$(strLine, InStr(1, strLine, ":") + 1))`
5. Finally, compare it to your search string.

   `LTrim$(Mid$(strLine, InStr(1, strLine, ":") + 1)) = strSearch`

---

In short, change this:

```
If InStr(1, strLine, strSearch, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
```

To this:

```
If LTrim$(Mid$(strLine, InStr(1, strLine, ":") + 1)) = strSearch Then
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, you want to make sure that the string matched in the file is exactly the same as the first value.

One suggestion is to check for the strSearchValue concatenated with a delimiting character.

For Example if "sample data 1 : fol1_fol2_SMPTR" is followed with a space, you could check using 
    `If InStr(1,strLine, strSearch & " ",vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then...`

Otherwise, if the input values just need to match the line exactly, and there are no other characters, then you could just use 
`If strSearch = strLine Then...`

Thanks